# Magento - Show out of stock products last

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9 and I have this code line that i am using in /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php :

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()
                ->joinField(
                    'inventory_in_stock', 
                    'cataloginventory_stock_item', 
                    'is_in_stock', 
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    'is_in_stock>=0', 
                    'left')
                ->setOrder('inventory_in_stock','desc');
```

but nothing happened.

Can someone help me?
Thank in advance!

Comment: try `addAttributeToSort('inventory_in_stock', 'desc');` instead of setOrder

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You must add this code :

```
$this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array('_inventory_table'=>$this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_item')),
            "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",
            array('is_in_stock', 'manage_stock')
        );
        $this->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('on_top',
        '(CASE WHEN (((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 1) AND (_inventory_table.is_in_stock = 1)) OR  ((_inventory_table.use_config_manage_stock = 0) AND (1 - _inventory_table.manage_stock + _inventory_table.is_in_stock >= 1))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
         array());
        $this->getSelect()->order('on_top DESC');
```

Just before

```
if ($attribute == 'price' && $storeId != 0) {
in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php
```

Or in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php` if you have Magento `1.7.0.0`

or you can used this magento module

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/show-out-of-stocks-products-at-bottom.html
```

Comment: In my Magento's version, Collection.php file in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Collection.php is empty...